# Crystal report print button open pdf page

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, reporting

I am working in Crystal report at a project. I have a requirement and I need Help On following metter:

I have crystal Report in my webpage. The .net Crystal report viewer views this report. But when I click the print button on crytal report viewer it exports the report in .pdf format. I don't want to click again and again. I want to open the print dialog Box instead of exporting at .pdf formet.

Is it Possible??? if yes How???

Help Me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see it is definitely doable. Some people also raise custom JavaScript print dialogs instead of the MS one. Here are a couple of examples of more traditional print dialogs:

1. This SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362230/crystal-report-printing-default-printer) shows you how to do it with and without a print dialog box.
2. Look at the bottom [example](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/showthread.php?t=97210) on this thread