# Updating crystal reports data source location remove the parameters somehow

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

Today I got a crystal report from one of my client to do some changes. It has some weird looking parameters in it(please look into image). The problem is when I update the data source location it removes some of those parameters(all which are weird). I am expecting them to be somehow attached to data source and while updating data source the link or association some how broke.

What are those parameters, what are there benefits over normal parameters and how could I make them persistent over data source location updation.

[image]

**Edit 1**

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the parameters and checked what they are (right-click on parameter -> Edit)? The cylinder indicates that the paramters are used in the data selection. So check the Select Expert for those parameters.

Comment: @campagnolo_1 I've added the image of edit parameter, the only unexpected thing here is its type, which is disable for some reason.

Comment: Are you using Stored Procedure to get the data for this report?

Comment: hmm they look SQL Server Stored Procedure parameters. Is the reports data source a stored proc?

Comment: @ConradFrix Yeah, can you please let me know how to pass parameters to reports dynamically so they never prompt end-user for the values.

Comment: You need to use SetParameter [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362426/119477)

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the report uses a Stored Procedure as the data source, which is why the parameters look different than the normal rectangle symbol. I would suggest to check the stored procedure to see what it entails. It could well be that it has changed from the original report and that's why some of the parameters "disappear" when you update it.

Comment: What you are suggesting here makes absolute sense to me, but I always use ADO.net dataset as reports data source, can you please suggest me or refer me to some links which helps me know how to use sql server as data source of reports.

Comment: I suggest to do a Google search on that. There are several ways to go about it (create a DSN, use a SQL Command) and I don't know which one would suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the stored procedure has the same parameters in the old and the new database. The report will update the parameters automatically if you change the source stored procedure. If you want to replace the stored procedure with a dataset you need to rebuild the report using a xsd